# Siberia v2 microphone will not work with OS X or Windows XP in Boot Camp

Tags: imac, bootcamp, headphones, microphone

Is there a workaround to get my Siberia v2 headset microphone to work with OS X or Boot Camp Windows XP?

In OS X, the microphone is recognized but will not let me switch to it in Steam. The built-in microphone still picks up everything. I tried to switch to into in the Sound options.

In Boot Camp Windows, the microphone isn't even recognized. Under `Control Panel > Sound options > Voice...` the only option I have is for the built-in mic.

I have one of the newer iMacs.

Answer (score 1):

There are two options for using a Siberia v2 with a Mac. The first is to buy the one that has the proper connector already (they have one with the 3-ring connector) or to buy the standard, dual connector audio/mic v2 and use an adapter such as [Headset Buddy](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002SK66OY) to connect.

The adapter works fine, however, but there is a ritual associated with using this headset with that adapter on my later 2012 MBPr (running 10.8.3). It seems that if I mute/turn off the microphone (using the switch on the headset cable) before plugging it in, then the mic will be recognized by my Mac. But, if I do *not* mute the mic, it won't recognize the headset mic. When I disconnect, mute, and reconnect, it works flawlessly even after enabling the mic. It doesn't sound weak or lossy as other posters have stated that non-powered mics would.

Obviously YMMV, and I did see another poster that said he had to turn his mic *off* before plugging it in (not sure what headset he was using, though).